Enable Global File Search for Synced Google Drive Folders in Ubuntu
I've synced my Google Drive with Ubuntu (24.04 LTS) using GNOME Online Accounts, and I can access my Google Drive folder and its subfolders locally. However, I'm facing an issue with file search in Ubuntu's File Explorer and FSearch.
Currently, I need to navigate to the specific subfolder where a file exists to locate it. The search functionality doesn't work across the entire synced Google Drive folder structure, which makes it inconvenient to find files quickly.
Is there a way to enable global search across all subfolders in the synced Google Drive folder?
